# Finding the charge of an insulated conductor using Green's Reciprocation Theorem

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, insulators

I am trying to work old E&M notes to prepare for a plasma physics class coming up but I'm getting stumped on using Green's reciprocation theorem. The problem is as follows:

> Consider two insulated spherical conductors. Let the first have radius $a$. Let the second be sufficiently small that it can effectively be treated as a point charge, and let it also be located a distance $b > a$ from the center of the first. Suppose that the first conductor is uncharged, and that the second carries a charge $q$. What is the potential of the first conductor? [Hint: Consider the result proved in Problem 3 which says that for two insulated conductors (1 & 2) they will have $\phi_1=\phi_2$]

I started out by considering the point charge (labeled as 2) with charge $q$, having a potential $\phi_2 = \frac{kq}{r}$. Using $\rho_2 = -\epsilon_0 \nabla^{2}\phi_2$ (from Maxwell's eq) and $\sigma_2 = -\epsilon_0\nabla\phi_2$ (from $E=\epsilon_0\sigma$), I get that $\rho_2=0$ and $\sigma_2 = -\epsilon_0\frac{kq}{r^2}$.

Considering the reciprocal scenario where the sphere has a charge $q$, we know that $\rho_1 =\frac{q}{V_1}$ and $\sigma_1= \frac{q}{S_1}$ where $V_1$ and $S_1$ are the volume and surface area of the sphere of radius $a$ respectively.

By Green's reciprocation theorem we have:

$$\int_{V_1}\rho_1 \phi_2 dV_1 + \int_{S_1}\sigma_1 \phi_2 dS_1 = \int_{V_2}\rho_2 \phi_1 dV_2 + \int_{S_2}\sigma_2 \phi_1 dS_2 $$
and
$$\frac{q}{V_1}\int_{V_1}\phi_2 dV_1 + \frac{q}{S_1}\int_{S_1}\phi_2 dS_1 = \int_{S_2}\sigma_2 \phi_1 dS_2. $$

But I get stuck here in knowing how to proceed next, specifically on the RHS with $\sigma_2$ and evaluating the integrals. I feel like $\phi_2$ should have something to do with the radius $a$ which can come in from $V_1$ and $S_1$. Do you all have any tips or hints on how to solve this?

Comment: $\sigma_2 = -\epsilon_0 \frac{q}{r^2}$, what is $r$ here?   $\rho_1 = q / V_1$ and $\sigma_1= q / S_1$, what is the meaning of this sentence? How can the sphere has both $\rho$ and $\sigma$ give charge $q$?

Comment: The $r$ is the distance from the point charge. Honestly, I'm not too sure about $\rho_1$ and $\rho_1$ represent. I know the first is charge density and the second is charge density, but would both exist for a conductor? When is one used versus another?